# Back button in AppBar

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

Is it "legal" to have the back button in the top AppBar? The client thinks that it is a good idea and I need to know if it passes certification or not to have a good reason to disagree.

Comment: I don't think there are any hard certification requirements regarding the UI and your acceptance to the Windows App Store. That said, Microsoft has stated that the top app bar should be used for navigation and the bottom app bar should be used for non-navigation actions. Additionally, it is suggested that the app bar be used for actions that are not a part of the displayed page's functional requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've scoured the certification guidelines and I can't find any reference to the back button or a standard control scheme.

The AppBar isn't really intuitive. Some users may not be aware of it and will be unable to navigate between pages leading to frustration and potentially bad reviews and uninstalls.

I tend to think of the App Bar as a place to put advanced controls - a place where users who want extra functionality are likely to look.

As I can't find any reference to it in the guidelines - if it's not in the guidelines then it's technically legal.

Guidelines:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694083.aspx

Comment: I'd agree.  It's legal but it's really bad HCI.  Most people will put the back button next to the title.  If the client pushes then do a usability test - give a set of the clients employees a simple set of tasks to do in the app, including going back.  If they all can't find the back button then you've got your argument why it's a bad idea.

Comment: The back button is a fairly important control that the user is required to interact with if they want to return to a previous page. As such, I feel that it is not fit for an app bar (which should be reserved for non-required actions).

Answer (score 0):

It's completely legal, I've even used in some of my apps, no problem in certification or whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

During App certification, they check for the following factors http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694083.aspx

It doesn't matter what font you are using and whether you are following metro guidelines ot not.

Coming to your question, Yes it's legal to add backbutton to top app bar and that's how you should do it.